# Email regex used Jquery does not work in .Net C#

Tags: c#, jquery, .net, regex, fluentvalidation

**CONTEXT:**
I have an email regex that is used in jquery while registration of users which goes as follows. It was already present in the database before I began with the project and I assume it is correct:

```
/^(?!.*\.{2})[A-Z0-9_%][\w\.\+\-]*[a-zA-Z0-9._%]@[a-zA-Z0-9]([\w\.\-]+)((\.([a-zA-Z]){2,4})+)$/im
```

After validating on the frontend, the registration process calls an API which validates the email using Fluent Validation.

**REQUIREMENT:**

Through jquery, a certain email (testuser.@domain.com) is successfully validated but the fluent validation disapproves it. There is a requirement to get such email successfully validated and registered.

**ISSUE:**
I found that we can pass our custom regex in the Fluent Validation itself using the below code:

```
var RegisterEmailRegexPatternstring = userSettingService.CurrentUserSettings.RegisterEmailRegexPattern.Replace("/^","").Replace("/im","") ?? @"^(?!.*\.{2})[A-Z0-9_%][\w\.\+\-]*[a-zA-Z0-9_%]@[a-zA-Z0-9]([\w\-]+)((\.([a-zA-Z]){2,4})+)$";
            
var RegisterEmailRegexPattern = new Regex(RegisterEmailRegexPatternstring);
            
RuleFor(x => x.email).Matches(RegisterEmailRegexPattern);
```

But the regex which is used to validate in jquery fails in .NET/C# and I'm unable to find the reason behind it.

**QUESTION:**

1. Why does a regex which works in jquery but fails in .NET/C#?
2. What can be done to prevent this issue in this case?

Comment: `.Replace("/im","")` here you are removing the multi-line and case insensitive options from regex. You can try with `var RegisterEmailRegexPattern = new Regex(RegisterEmailRegexPatternstring, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Multiline);`

Comment: There are different variants of Regular Expressions (much as there are different variants of markdown). A regex that works in the regex engine that JQuery uses may not be supported by the regex engine that .NET uses. There are regex test tools that support multiple variants. Such a tool could help find the reason why the regex doesn't work on the .NET regex engine and could help develop a possible common expression that works in both engines.

Answer (score -1):

There are some differences between the regex engines used by jQuery and .NET/C#, which may cause some patterns to work differently or not at all. Some of the common differences are:

**jQuery uses the JavaScript regex engine**, which does not support named capture groups, lookbehind assertions, or Unicode character classes. .NET/C# supports all of these features and more.

**jQuery uses the /g flag to indicate a global search**, which means it will find all matches in the input string. .NET/C# does not use flags, but has methods such as Regex.Matches or Regex.Replace that can perform global searches.

**jQuery uses the /i flag to indicate a case-insensitive search**, which means it will ignore the difference between uppercase and lowercase letters. .NET/C# uses the RegexOptions.IgnoreCase enumeration value to achieve the same effect.

**jQuery uses the /m flag to indicate a multiline search**, which means it will treat the ^ and $ anchors as matching the start and end of each line, rather than the whole input string. .NET/C# uses the RegexOptions.Multiline enumeration value to achieve the same effect.

In your case, I think the problem is caused by the /m flag in your jQuery regex. This flag makes the ^ and $ anchors match the start and end of each line in the input string, rather than the whole string. This means that your regex will accept an email that has a newline character (\n) in it, such as testuser.@domain.com\n. However, this is not a valid email address, and it will fail in .NET/C#, which does not use the /m flag by default.

To fix this issue, you can either remove the /m flag from your jQuery regex or add the RegexOptions.Multiline value to your .NET/C# regex. This will make both regex engines behave consistently and reject invalid emails that contain newline characters.

You can use this approach to validate email in C#:

```
public static Regex EmailRegex =>
            new(@"\A(?:[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?)\Z", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

bool isValidEmail = EmailRegex.IsMatch("test@gmail.com");
```

Comment: var registerEmailRegexPatternString = @"^(?!.*\.{2})[A-Z0-9_%][\w\.\+\-]*[a-zA-Z0-9-_.%]@[a-zA-Z0-9]([\w\.\-]+)((\.([a-zA-Z]){2,4})+)$";



var RegisterEmailRegexPattern = new Regex(registerEmailRegexPatternString, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Multiline);



RuleFor(x => x.Email).Matches(RegisterEmailRegexPattern)



This is what I had tried and it does not allow a simple email: testuser@domain.com

Anything missing here?

Comment: first of all define this regex like this:  public static Regex EmailRegex =>
            new(@"\A(?:[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?)\Z", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
and then use it:  bool isEmail = EmailRegex.IsMatch("test@gmail.com");

Comment: I included this approach in my response.